# TabBar with floating action button in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/litslink/reactnative-curved-tabbar-dc62e681c24d) where they created a TaBar with a Floating Button, and after adding the code, it seems to work really well on iOS, as shown below:

[image: ios-sample]

On Android, it is a different case; it appears the floating button gets cropped right where the BottomBar ends, as shown below:

[image: android-sample]

I do not understand why this is happening, below is the code

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import {
  BottomTabBar,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { FontAwesome as Icon } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { TabBarAdvancedButton } from "./TabBarAdvancedButton";
import { isIphoneX } from "src/utils/deviceHelpers";
import { DARKTEXT, WHITE } from "src/styles/colors";
import { BlankScreen } from "src/screens";
import { Badge } from "react-native-paper";

const BottomBar = createBottomTabNavigator();

type Props = {
  barColor?: string;
  isBtnDisabled?: boolean;
  hasNotification?: boolean;
};

export const TabBar: React.FC<Props> = ({
  barColor = WHITE,
  isBtnDisabled = false,
  hasNotification = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <BottomBar.Navigator
      backBehaviour="initialRoute"
      name="BarStack"
      tabBar={(props) => (
        <View style={styles.navigatorContainer}>
          <BottomTabBar {...props} />
          {isIphoneX() && (
            <View
              style={[
                styles.xFillLine,
                {
                  backgroundColor: barColor,
                },
              ]}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      )}
      tabBarOptions={{
        showIcon: true,
        style: styles.navigator,
        tabStyle: {
          backgroundColor: barColor,
        },
      }}
    >
      <BottomBar.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={BlankScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <BottomBar.Screen
        name="Lists"
        component={BlankScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="file" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <BottomBar.Screen
        name="Rocket"
        component={BlankScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => (
            <TabBarAdvancedButton bgColor={barColor} {...props} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomBar.Screen
        name="Alerts"
        component={BlankScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <View>
              <Icon name="bell" size={24} color={color} />
              {hasNotification && <Badge />}
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomBar.Screen
        name="search"
        component={BlankScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="search" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomBar.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  navigatorContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.22,
    shadowRadius: 2.22,
  },
  navigator: {
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    elevation: 30,
  },
  tabIconStyle: {
    color: DARKTEXT,
  },
  xFillLine: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 34,
  },
});

export default TabBar;
```

And the Floating button:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { BottomTabBarButtonProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/lib/typescript/src/types';
import { FontAwesome as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { TabBg } from './svg';

type Props = BottomTabBarButtonProps & {
  bgColor?: string;
};

export const TabBarAdvancedButton: React.FC<Props> = ({
  bgColor,
  ...props
}) => (
  <View
    style={styles.container}
    pointerEvents="box-none"
  >
    <TabBg
      color={bgColor}
      style={styles.background}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={props.onPress}
    >
      <Icon
        name="rocket"
        style={styles.buttonIcon}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: 75,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  background: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
  },
  button: {
    top: -22.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 27,
    backgroundColor: '#E94F37',
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#F6F7EB'
  }
});
```

Comment: Does adding ```zIndex: 2``` in your TabBarAdvancedButton ```styles.container``` works?

Comment: @FelixFilipi unfortunately not. This was working a few days back until I updated my dependencies, it sucks because I cannot downgrade, I need. solution.